# How to check if all strings in an array start with upper case letter using forAll?

Tags: java, uppercase, forall, functional-java

If I have an array of names, how do I check if they all start with an upper case letter using forall (or something else functional)?

```
String[] names = {"Linda", "Peter", "Carol", "Paul"};
names.forall(name -> Character.isUpperCase(name.charAt(0)));
```

that is wrong and I'm not really familiar with higher order functions yet so I could use some help.

Comment: `names` is an array, and there is no `forall` method on arrays.

Comment: You are trying to use forEach function in Java, right? Then use this:  ```public static void main(String []args){
        String[] names = {"Linda", "Peter", "Carol", "Paul"}; 
        for(String myName : names){
            if(Character.isUpperCase(myName.codePointAt(0))){
                System.out.println(myName);
            }
        }
     }```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Stream.allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
String[] names = {"Linda", "Peter", "Carol", "Paul"};
boolean allUpper = Arrays.stream(names).allMatch(name -> Character.isUpperCase(String.codePointAt(0)));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8+:

```
Arrays.stream(names).allMatch(name -> Character.isUpperCase(name.codePointAt(0)));
```

Or:

```
Stream.of(names).allMatch(name -> Character.isUpperCase(name.codePointAt(0)));
```

Note that I replaced `charAt(0)` with `codePointAt(0)` so it supports Unicode characters in the supplemental planes.